# Arrays.copyOf in java 1.4

Tags: java, key, aes, arrays

I'm trying to use Arrays.copyOf but my codebase is Java 1.4.  How would I go about using System.arraycopy instead?  I'm having some issues.

I need to find an alternative for this line:

key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);

Comment: Needless to say you should not use 1.4 anymore, as it is unsupported and won't get security updates.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is arraycopy:

```
int[] copyTo = new int[16];
System.arraycopy(key, 0, copyTo, 0, key.length);
```

I'm not entirely sure that java 1.4 has it though.

**EDIT**

Yep! [Here it is!](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/j2sdk-1.4.2/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

Comment: I think that one may be in since 1.0, if not earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
int[] copy = new int[key.length];
System.arraycopy(key, 0, copy, 0, key.length);
```